# jQuery insert div into td

Tags: jquery, html-table, insert

I want to add div into a table when I click the alert button, and the div should insert after class "name2", but when I clicked the button, the original text were gone, and the test() function can't work, how to fix it?

```js
function test() {
    alert('test')
}
$('#form').on('click', '.test', function () {
 var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $('.one',$row).each(function() {
        $(this).html($('<div class="name"></div>').text('Watson')).inserAfter('.name2');
    });
    test();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="form">
    <tr>
        <th>Name Table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">
            <div class="name1">Henry</div>
            <div class="name2">Harry</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><button type="button" class="test">Alert</button></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">
            <div class="name1">Berry</div>
            <div class="name2">Terry</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><button type="button" class="test">Alert</button></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysa99n1p/10/)

Comment: What do you want the end result to be?

Comment: try .append() instead of .html()

Comment: pop-up "test" alert, and add "Watson" after every name, when I click the button.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef it worked after I use .append(), but how to make test() function work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your case** no need to use `.each` so you can directly use

```
var $name2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name2');
```

and you can use **InsertAfter()** like this

```
function test() {
    alert('test')
}
$('#form').on('click', '.test', function () {
    var $name2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name2');
    ($('<div class="name"></div>').text('Watson')).insertAfter($name2);
    test();
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ysa99n1p/16/)

Comment: @S.P. you Welcome .. Very Good Luck to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Trt to use append instead of html

```js
function test() {
    alert('test')
}
$('#form').on('click', '.test', function () {
 var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $('.one',$row).each(function() {
        $(this).append($('<div class="name"></div>').text('Watson')).inserAfter('.name2');
    });
    test();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="form">
    <tr>
        <th>Name Table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">
            <div class="name1">Henry</div>
            <div class="name2">Harry</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><button type="button" class="test">Alert</button></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">
            <div class="name1">Berry</div>
            <div class="name2">Terry</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><button type="button" class="test">Alert</button></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Thx a lot! But I don't know why the test() function can't work?

Comment: the answers is correct but i don't know why the function .insertAfter give a not exist error, so the script go in exception...so strange